# Is there a way to access a python method in another file that is reliant on another method without specifying self?

Tags: python, class, oop, methods

I have some trouble with creating a python class and methods, and I don't know how to resolve it.

I have 2 files, 1 file contains a class with multiple methods. 2 of these are:

```
def get_price_of(ticker: str) -> float:
    URL = 'https://api.kucoin.com/api/v1/market/orderbook/level1?symbol='
    r = requests.get(URL + ticker).json()
    return r['data']['price']

def get_price_of_list(self, tickers):
    prices = {}
    for ticker in tickers:
        prices[ticker] = self.get_price_of(ticker)
    return prices
```

So the `get_price_of_list` method utilises the `get_price_of` method.

My problem: When accessing the `get_price_of_list` from another file it now asks for 2 params: self and tickers. However, I don't need it to be an instance so is there any way to convert it to a static method while still being able to access the other function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. you can use `@staticmethod`.

As I can see in your `get_price_of` method, there is no need for your instance to be exist. You just pass a `ticker` and you get a result back. Same thing with `get_price_of_list`. They are kind of utility functions that happen to be inside the class namespace. You could also define them in module. But one advantage of using them inside a class is that they are now organized. Relevant functions accumulated inside a class namespace.

Change your methods to:

```py
    @staticmethod
    def get_price_of(ticker: str) -> float:
        URL = "https://api.kucoin.com/api/v1/market/orderbook/level1?symbol="
        r = requests.get(URL + ticker).json()
        return r["data"]["price"]

    @staticmethod
    def get_price_of_list(tickers):
        prices = {}
        for ticker in tickers:
            prices[ticker] = <CLASS_NAME>.get_price_of(ticker)
        return prices
```

Note that I changed `self` to the class name itself in `get_price_of_list`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the thing:

If you want it to be an instance. First, initiate the class *(pass in all args in the class)*. Then you can continue using the functions. Also, your `get_price_of()` function is missing `self` as the first parameter, which is why I suppose this approach fails at work.

**OR**

You can simply make them independent functions and remove self. Then, inside one function you can simply pass the parameter of the other.

Here's the code:

```
def get_price_of(ticker: str) -> float:
    URL = 'https://api.kucoin.com/api/v1/market/orderbook/level1?symbol='
    r = requests.get(URL + ticker).json()
    return r['data']['price']

def get_price_of_list(tickers):
    prices = {}
    for ticker in tickers:
        prices[ticker] = get_price_of(ticker)
    return prices
```